# Question on derivative

Tags: derivatives

I want to differentiate $H(p(t),q(t))=1 $ with respect to $t$, where $H:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a convex function.

I think that it is:

$\displaystyle \frac{dp}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial p}+ \frac{dq}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial q}=0$

right?

Please, thank you.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=\frac{dp}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial p}+ \frac{dq}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial q}$

Comment: So what I wrote is just ?

Comment: You wrote $\dots = 0$; the equals-zero isn't part of the derivative. (It's like saying "the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x=0$".) If you want to differentiate and then set the derivative equal to $0$ in a second step, that's fine, but it's important to recognize that those are indeed separate things to do.

Comment: so the defferential of $H(p(t),q(t))$ is $\displaystyle \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=\frac{dp}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial p}+ \frac{dq}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial q}$, ans because $H(p(t),q(t))=1$ then $\displaystyle \frac{dp}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial p}+ \frac{dq}{dt} \frac{\partial H(p,q)}{\partial q}=0$ right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want something we need a detailed notation flowery but enlightening.

- First of all use the implicit differentiation theorem:
  \begin{align}
  \left.\frac{d\!}{dt}\!F\big( q(t), p(t)\big)\right|_{t=t_0}
  =
  &
  \left.\frac{d\!}{dt}\!F\big( q_0, p(t)\big)\right|_{t=t_0}
  +
  \left.\frac{d\!}{dt}\!F\big( q(t), p_0\big)\right|_{t=t_0}
  \end{align}
  for $p_0=p(t_0)$ and $q_0=q(t_0)$.
- Second, use the chain rule

  $\qquad\left.\dfrac{d\!}{dt}\!F\big( q_0, p(t)\big)\right|_{t=t_0}=\left.\dfrac{d}{dt}p(t)\right|_{t=t_0}\!\cdot\; \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial p}F(p,q)\right|_{(p,q)=(p_0,q_0)},$

  $\qquad\left.\dfrac{d\!}{dt}\!F\big( q(t), p_0\big)\right|_{t=t_0}=\left.\dfrac{d}{dt}q(t)\right|_{t=t_0}\!\cdot\; \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q}F(p,q)\right|_{(p,q)=(p_0,q_0)}$

  to get
  \begin{align}
   \left.\frac{d\!}{dt}\!F\big( q(t), p(t)\big)\right|_{t=t_0}
  =
  &
  \left.\dfrac{d}{dt}p(t)\right|_{t=t_0}\!\cdot\; \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial p}F(p,q)\right|_{(p,q)=(p_0,q_0)}+
  \\
  +
  &
  \left.\dfrac{d}{dt}q(t)\right|_{t=t_0}\!\cdot\; \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q}F(p,q)\right|_{(p,q)=(p_0,q_0)}
  \end{align}